# How to pass multiple arguments to Spacebars helper from Meteor template?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I haven't been able to find a solid example out there.

```
Template.registerHelper("itemLookup", function(sku, property){
  return Items.findOne({sku: sku})[property];
});
```

How do I call this on the template?

I want to do something like:

```
{{ itemLookup sku="i3_4030U" property="title" }}
```

It should output

```
"Intel Core i3 4030U"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do not name template helpers parameters, they will be passed in the same order to your helper function :

```
{{ itemLookup "i3_4030U" "title" }}
```

EDIT :

> Why then do I see examples online where they are naming the template
>   helper parameters?

You can name parameters when including another template and you want to set its current data context to something else :

```
{{> childTemplate param1="A" param2="B"}}
```

In the child template markup you'll be able to reference `{{param1}}` and `{{param2}}`.

Another Handlebars helpers feature available in Spacebars is the "hash" optional argument value you can pass as the last argument to your helper parameters, you can use it like this :

HTML

```
{{helper "A" "B" namedParam1="C" namedParam2="D"}}
```

JS

```
Template.registerHelper("helper", function(param1, param2, options){
  console.log("param1 :", param1);
  console.log("param2 :", param2);
  if(options && options.hash){
    console.log("namedParam1 :", options.hash.namedParam1);
    console.log("namedParam2 :", options.hash.namedParam2);
  }
});
```

Comment: Guhhhhhhh...... thanks. Why then do I see examples online where they are naming the template helper parameters?

Comment: Edited my answer to cover named parameters use cases in Spacebars.

Comment: Thank you! This concise summary is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ok, one more question (I think). In certain helpers a `" "` is not required. `{{> afQuickField name="optionsButNoSelect" options=numSelectOptions noselect="true"}}` I'm pretty sure that `numSelectOptions` is not in quotes because it is the name of a helper that returns an object, right?

Comment: @saimeunt can you mix named and unnamed parameters in the same template call?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny : do not mix template inclusion syntax `{{> childTemplate}}` and helper syntax `{{helper}}` because they're not the same things. You're right in assuming that you don't need to quote parameter values that resolves to template helpers.

Comment: @Aaron : you can mix named and unnamed parameters in helper calls (see my example) but you have to name every arguments you pass to a child template when including it, note that using this feature will completely scrap the previous data context and replace it by the arguments you provide.